# Insert string in pandas column using regex if pattern is found

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string column in a dataframe and I'd like to insert a # to the begging of my pattern.

For example:
My pattern is the letters 'pr' followed by any amount of numbers. If in my column there is a value 'problem in pr123', I would change it to 'problem in #pr123'.

I'm trying a bunch of code snippets but nothing is working for me.

Tried to change the solution to replace for 'pr#123' but this didn't work either.

```
df['desc_clean'] = df['desc_clean'].str.replace(r'([p][r])(\d+)', r'\1#\2', regex=True)
```

What's the best way I can replace all values in this column when I find this pattern?

Comment: You need `df['desc_clean'] = df['desc_clean'].str.replace(r'(pr)(\d+)', r'\1#\2')` if you need `pr#123`. To get `#pr123`, you need  `df['desc_clean'].str.replace(r'pr\d+', r'#\g<0>')`. Add a word boundary, `\b`, in front of `pr` to match `pr` as a whole word.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much for your help @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `pr#123` you can use

```
df['desc_clean'] = df['desc_clean'].str.replace(r'(pr)(\d+)', r'\1#\2')
```

To get `#pr123`, you can use

```
df['desc_clean'].str.replace(r'pr\d+', r'#\g<0>')
```

To match `pr` as a whole word, you can add a word boundary, `\b`, in front of `pr`:

```
df['desc_clean'].str.replace(r'\bpr\d+', r'#\g<0>')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JCF2kJ/1).

Comment: This works great and solved my problem. Thanks for the help Wiktor!